# Delphi /w Indy 10: Get Content after ERROR 400 (idHTTP)

Tags: delphi, indy, idhttp

I am trying to get around the Indy idHTTP Component and have some issues retrieving the server response after a GET/PUT/POST if it's not 200 OK.
 Even if I disable the ProtocolException, Response.ResponseText AND the reutrned StringStream only show the 400 Error but not the content the server transmitted.

How can I get that data???

thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid discarding response body by `TIdHTTP` component in case of non-2xx status, you'd also need to use `hoWantProtocolErrorContent` among `HttpOptions`. Unfortunatelly these options are poorly documented even in help file shipped with RAD Studio help (<kbd>Help</kbd>→<kbd>Third-Party Help</kbd>→<kbd>Indy Library Help</kbd>).

To get the response body as a string use `Get`/`Put`/`Post` invariant that returns string, not `TIdHTTP.Response.ResponseText` or `TIdHTTP.ResponseText` for short which contains [status line of HTTP response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Response_message); e.g.: `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request`.

Sample code:

```
var
  IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
begin
  IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create();
  try
    IdHTTP.HTTPOptions := IdHTTP.HTTPOptions + [hoNoProtocolErrorException, hoWantProtocolErrorContent];
    Writeln(IdHTTP.ResponseText);
    Writeln;
    Writeln(IdHTTP.Get('https://postman-echo.com/status/400'));
  finally
    IdHTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Sample output:

> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
>
> {"status":400}

Comment: "*Unfortunatelly these options are poorly documented even in help file shipped with RAD Studio help*" - that is because Indy's documentation hasn't been updated in a LONG LONG time. A lot of new functionality added in Indy 10.6.x hasn't been documented yet, including `hoWantProtocolErrorContent`. That flag is described in [this blog post](https://www.indyproject.org/2016/01/10/new-tidhttp-flags-and-onchunkreceived-event/) on Indy's website, though